# firebase.json change public folder dynamically

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting, ionic4

I have an angular7/ionic4 app with 2 environments for staging and prod.

I can do

> ionic build
>
> ionic build --prod

This publishes the app in different folders I have set in angular.json

> dist/staging
>
> dist/prod

I also have 2 projects in firebase and can deploy to each

> firebase deploy -P staging
>
> firebase deploy -P default

However in firebase.json I can only set one hosting folder from where to pick the files up to send to firebase:

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "dist/prod"
}
```

So despite being able to deploy to different projects I can't seem to set which folder to deploy from.

I want

> firebase deploy -P default

to deploy files from dist/prod

and

> firebase deploy -P staging

to deploy files from dist/staging

Can I change firebase.json (or .firebaserc) to set which folder to deploy from for each environment / project ?

Comment: Sure, you can read, parse, and rewrite the contents of firebase.json.  I wouldn't recommend that, though, since you're supposed to check that file into source control.  I think you're better off having different entire project folders for each environment, and keeping their structures the same.

Comment: thanks, we do use GIT source control and I was hoping to stick to the GIT workflow - master branch (prod) and feature branches (staging). Your suggestion would work but it requires the same repo to be checked out in two separate workspaces, where one always stays on master and the other would be feature branches. Not impossible but open to someone in the team following their usual processes and checking out a feature branch in the master/prod workspace and deploying a feature branch to live! Shame I can't just set a build path for each project alias in firebase.json

Answer (score 2):

Associate the sites with a local target so Firebase knows which code to deploy where.

```
$ firebase target:apply hosting  staging  staging_project_name
$ firebase target:apply hosting  prod  production_project_name
```

And then edit the configuration in the `firebase.json` file as follows:

```
{
  "hosting": [ {
      "target": "staging", 
      "public": "dist/staging",
      "rewrites": [...] 
    },
    {
      "target": "prod", 
      "public": "dist/prod",
      "rewrites": [...] 
    }
  ]
}
```

And then you can deploy as follows:

```
$ firebase deploy --only hosting:staging -P staging
$ firebase deploy --only hosting:prod -P default
```